# Restangular post data as payload not query string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest, restangular

So right now I have my backend service to register a new user to our system from following URL:

```
/api/users/register
```

Using Restangular always causes post requests to be sent either as **query string**

```
Restangular.all('users').post("register",registerData)
```

or with **headers**

```
 Restangular.all('users').one("register").customPOST('','','',{name:"xyz"})
```

the question here, how to post registeration form parameters as payload ?

**Payload:**
[image: payload]

**Query String:**
[image]

**Headers:**
[image: headers]

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the data as the first parameter:

```
Restangular.all('users').one("register").customPOST({name:"xyz"}, '', {}, {});
```

The documentation at https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/blob/master/README.md seems quite complete. Good to see!